# Postgres: Convert `character varying[]` to string

Tags: django, postgresql

After loading data from a django `dumpdata` using `loaddata` one column was somehow converted from character varying(100)[] to character varying(100)[][]. How can I collapse the inner array.

Example:
previous data

```
{frank}
```

uploaded data

```
{{f,r,a,n,k}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Converting Query:

```
with tb1 as (
    select '{{f,r,a,n,k}}'::text[][] as pdata
)
select array_agg(a2.pdata2) from 
( 
    select string_agg(a1.pdata1, '') as pdata2 from 
    (
        select unnest(pdata) as pdata1 from tb1 
    ) a1 
) a2
```